# Get variable value with line break similar to paste with new line in jquery

Tags: jquery

When I copy and paste text with new line in input box, the required result is not populated.
I have following line of code:

```
A & C - John Doe - 1221
P & C - Hexaa - 122
```

When I copy this text in paste in input box, It seems to be like this

```
A & C - John Doe - 1221 P & C - Hexaa - 122
```

But it actually have a new line inserted between the code. How can I equate both the text when pasted in input box?

Comment: What kind of *"input box"*? Only `<textarea>` supports multiple lines, `<input>` does not

Comment: pasting multiple lines in input box, not textarea.

Comment: *"But it actually have a new line inserted between the code"* Please do a [mcve] of that. When I paste the two lines above into an `input`, the newline is converted to a space, as expected. If you mean you *want* the newline preserved, you can't use an `input`, you need a `textarea` (or contenteditable element).

Comment: [`<input>` type "text" ~ *"A **single-line** text field. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_<input>_types)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is easily answered by [reading the fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_<input>_types)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for mentioning [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content), I always forget that one